# GridView rowcommand event is not working in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView inside an UpdatePanel which fires the RowCommand event. While firing the RowCommand event i assign the e.CommandArgument value to a label but it does not show the effect. I set breakpoint over the event during execuation it set the label text property but after getting out of the event, The label lost its value and went to its previous text. I stored the value in ViewState and Session but still it did not work. Below is my code.

The GridView1_RowCommand event here want to assign value to lblValue which is the problem

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
      {
            lblValue.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
      }
}
```

Here i want to delete the record from the database through the label value

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(lblValue.Text);
        conn.RegionalBusinessUnits.Remove(conn.RegionalBusinessUnits.Where(rbu => rbu.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
        conn.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is the markup

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="BoxStyle" >
    <div class="header"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlBack" runat="server"><img src="../images/back-icon.png" alt="Go Back" height="20" width="20" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;" /></asp:HyperLink> &nbsp; Regional Department Unit List</div>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Delete</h1>
            <p>This will guide you through the delete process</p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <p><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" /></p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="contents">
        <center>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="RBUEntityDataSource" CssClass="gridview" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" EnableViewState="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Region" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" OnClick="lbUpdate_Click">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="lbDelete_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="RBUEntityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ChemonicsDBEntities" DefaultContainerName="ChemonicsDBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="RegionalBusinessUnits" Select="it.[Id], it.[Region]" OrderBy="it.[Id] asc" Where="it.[DeletedBy] = 0">
                    </asp:EntityDataSource>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code with label inside the update panel

Answer (score 0):

lblValue isn't being updated as it is outside UpdatePanel1. If you move your UpdatePanel1 with ContentTemplate up to directly under the ScriptManager, it should work. Be sure to also put the

```
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

at the very bottom.

You can then remove the Trigger and change the UpdatePanel "UpdateMode" to "Always"

Comment: I moved the lblValue to UpdatePanel1 but still it is not working.

Comment: Please update your post with the label inside the UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDocuments" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="DocumentID">                                      
<Columns>                                        

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
    <ItemTemplate>                                                
        <asp:Button ID="btnDocumentViewAttachmentInGrid" runat="server" Text="View Attachment" CommandName="ViewAttachment" CausesValidation="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

My button click I was trying to stream a file to the client, but got the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed." since I was on an update panel.  I tried registering the datagridview for postback, nothing worked.  Finally, in the code, I tried this:

```
Protected Sub gvDocuments_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDocuments.RowCreated
    Try

        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

            Dim btnDocumentViewAttachmentInGrid As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnDocumentViewAttachmentInGrid")
            btnDocumentViewAttachmentInGrid.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()
            ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(btnDocumentViewAttachmentInGrid)

        End If




    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle error here
    End Try
End Sub
```

...and then I could stream the file like this:

```
Protected Sub gvDocuments_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvDocuments.RowCommand
    Try

        If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
            gvDocuments.SelectedIndex = e.CommandArgument


        ElseIf e.CommandName = "ViewAttachment" Then


                Dim iDocumentID As Int64 = gvDocuments.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Value

                Dim oRows() As DataRow = dtDocs.Select("DocumentID = " & iDocumentID.ToString())
                If oRows.Length > 0 Then
                    Dim oRow As DataRow = oRows(0)

                    Dim strFileName As String = oRow("NetworkPath").ToString()

                    Dim strJustTheName As String = oRow("DocumentID").ToString() & "." & oRow("FileNameExtension").ToString()
                    strFileName &= strJustTheName


                    Response.Clear()
                    Response.ClearHeaders()
                    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=""{0}""", strJustTheName))
                    Response.TransmitFile(strFileName)
                    Response.Flush()
                    Response.End()
                End If



        End If



    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle error
    End Try
End Sub
```

...and BOOM goes the dynamite, totally works!  :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case not, but may be you add control to GridView with same ID, You must have unique ID.
I had this problem, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

on Page_Load must be rebinding the gridview like this

`If (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     bindhere()
  }`